# The color drifts to white where there is light

Tags: color

So the problem is on the picture. Feels like it's about the light, but i can't find it by tweeking the stuff.
Could you help, please?
thanks!
[image]

Comment: You should post images of the full node network for your material as well as your world background and also post the settings for any lights you're using.

Comment: so if it's because of the light, select it and in the Properties panel > Object Data > Light, decrease the Power (or Strength for the Sun)

Comment: Try reducing the roughness of your specular reflections. 0.5 is high. Also check the width or angle of your light